# Display elements from nested SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, collections, sorteddictionary

I have list:

```
ProjectTaskList = new SortedDictionary<string, SortedDictionary<string, string>>();
```

I try to display all the elements from the list:

```
foreach (var itemList in ProjectTaskList)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Value: " + itemList.Value + ", Key: " + itemList.Key);                
}
```

How can I display element from nested `SortedDictionary<string, string>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To display the key and then all the key/value pair for each `itemList`:

```
foreach (var itemList in ProjectTaskList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {itemList.Key}");

    foreach (var entry in itemList.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Value: {entry.Value}, Key: {entry.Key}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through each key to display values from nested dictionary.

something like

```
foreach(var key in ProjectTaskList.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key);

    //Using KeyValue pair
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in ProjectTaskList[key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nested key : {0}, Nested value : {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
    }
}
```